# Modify the InitialChildData property of a SharePoint Workflow ReplicatorActivity

Tags: 2007, workflow

Does anybody know if it's possible to modify the InitialChildData collection of a ReplicatorActivity within SharePoint Workflow such that new instances of the activity to be replicated are spawned?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement your own **public IList replicatorActivity1_InitialChildData1** getter (which you bind to your ReplicatorActivity.InitialChildData), you can dynamically populate your collection right inside this property implementation.

The child activity for your ReplicatorActivity will be replicated for each item in the IList returned by your getter.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks Jaap, this is most helpful.

What I wondered was, when I dynamically add to the InitialChildData collection, will the replicator know that it needs to spawn new replicated activities?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add items to it after your getter has executed? I don't know to be honest. Why would you want to do that? My understanding is that the replicator fetches the InitialChildData by calling your bound property right before it starts replicating the child Activity. There is not much time between those steps :)